# macOS Music App: Why adding and then removing album artwork increases song file size?

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, music, music.app

When I add `.m4a` song to the Apple Music library, then add album artwork, then delete album artwork, the song file size increases by exactly `4 096 bytes`.

Why? And how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Question... are you actually adding metadata to the file, or just to the library?

Comment: Well, I change it by clicking on the song in the Music app, then click artwork and then add artwork. To delete I then click the artwork and use the delete key. I don't really know what the Music app is doing behind the scenes...